# MongoDB: Atomic Updates & Array Comparisons

Tags: php, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

**EDIT : Solution 3 (What I am Using)**

```
db.update(
    { 
        _id: ObjectId("..playerId..."),
        "OutstandingRewards.Id": {$all:[Outstanding, Ids, From PHP]}
    }, 
    {
        $pull: {"OutstandingRewards": {"Id": {$in:[Outstanding, Ids, From PHP]}}},
        $addToSet: {"GameObjects":{$each:[New, Rewards, From, PHP]}}
    },
);
```

This atomic update ensures that all the Outstanding Ids that I wish to claim still exist in `OutstandingRewards[]` at the time I wish to remove them and add in the the relevant processed rewards to `GameObjects[]`.  Further more, using the `$addToSet` operator ensures that no duplicate entries are inserted into `GameObjects[]`.

Solution based on Neil Lunn's answer below!

**Original Qn:**

Writing a DB for a game with claimable rewards, data struct as follows:

```
.
.
"OutstandingRewards" : [ 
    {
        "Type" : 0,
        "Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a0")
    }, 
    {
        "Type" : 1,
        "Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a2")
    },
],
"GameObjects":[
    {
        "Type" : 1,
        "Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a5")
    },
    {
        "Type" : 3,
        "Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a9")
    },
],
.
.
```

Iam trying to implement a function where my PHP script takes in an array of Ids for the outstanding rewards which the player wants to claim, process the reward items, and insert the new processed entry to `GameObjects:[]`

Correct me if iam wrong but since `$elemMatch` only returns 1 matched element, I just perform a

```
db.find(
    { _id: ObjectId("..playerId...")}, 
    {_id: 0, "OutstandingRewards": 1, "GameObjects":1}
)
```

Match all the rewards they wanted to claim on the PHP side, and assign them the objects.

To enforce the transactional property of the assignment operation(s), **I've come up with 2 solutions and would like to know which would be better performance wise (or if Iam getting this totally wrong, in terms of design or otherwise).**

#### Solution 1:

Store the entire `GameObject[]`(which could grow large, 100 maybe 1,000 objects) locally in a PHP array, append any claimed rewards to this array and rewrite the entire `GameObject[]` at the same time the `OutstandingRewards[]` objects are removed:

```
db.update({ _id: ObjectId("..playerId...")}, 
    {
        $pull: {"OutstandingRewards": {"Id": {$in:$PHPClaimIdsArray}}},
        $set: {"GameObjects":$PHPNewRewardsArray}
    },
);
```

Iam worried that this might be memory intensive and will produce a lot of redundant writing when `GameObjects[]` is large.

#### Solution 2:

**For each** reward the user wants to claim, perform one 'findAndModify' call:

```
db.findAndModify( 
    query: { 
        _id: ObjectId("..playerId..."),
        "OutstandingRewards": {$elemMatch: {"Id": $rewardId}}
    },
    update: {
        $pull: {"OutstandingRewards": {"Id": $rewardId}},
        $push: {"GameObjects":$rewardObject}
    }
)
```

Iam worried in this case that the PHP - MongoDb server communication and multiple write overheads are going to kill me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you **Solution 3** to this in which case you would be using [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to take all of the items off of the "OustandingRewards" list and then using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier in order to add those items to the "GameObjects" array at once.

The form here means that `$pull` in fact takes a "query" object as it's argument. The most obvious to apply here is the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator with each of the "Id" values you want to remove.

So if your "picked list" for example just happened to be both of the current "Oustanding" items (already "de-serialized" to PHP data) then you would do something like:

```
# $input = array from JSON
# [
#   { "Type" : 0,"Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a0")}, 
#   { "Type" : 1, Id" : ObjectId("53c7b54f12727064000000a2")}
# ],

function getIds($v)
{
    return $v["Id"];
}

$ids = array_map("getIds",$input);

$collection->findAndModify(
    array( 
        '_id' => $playerId,
        'OutstandingRewards.Id' => array(
            '$in' => $ids
        ),
        'GameObjects' => array( 
            '$nin' => $input
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$pull' => array(
            'OutstandingRewards' => array (
                'Id' => array( '$in' => $ids )
            )
        ),
        '$push' => array( 
            'GameObjects' => (
                '$each' => $input,
                '$slice' => 10000
            )
        )
    ),
    null,
    array( 'new' => true )
)
```

I have constructed the "query" portion there of the the statement in a particularly "paranoid" form. Meaning that it employs both `$in` and [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operations on the "OustandingRewards" and "GameObjects" respectively so the query will not in fact match if the arrays do not in fact contain ( or not contain ) the objects that are presented in the `$input` array.

The arguments to `$pull` is the "query" that uses `$in` to remove the items that match that query.

In the `$push` operation, the `$each` modifier in fact takes an array as it's argument. So that means that **all** of the elements from that array are applied in the singular "push" operation rather than employing a loop with several updates.

The [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier is mandatory in MongoDB versions prior to 2.6. The purpose is to "limit" the number of elements that the array can possibly contain when used with such an operation. Generally this is considered a good idea, but in latest versions you do not need it. Here it is just set to a number you expect to be larger than the possible elements of the array so that nothing is taken away.

Of course in latest versions you can modify the levels of "paranoia" and handling here as [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) can also use the `$each` modifier. This time just as JavaScript now the PHP syntax is explained:

```js
var input; // the same JavaScript object
var ids = input.map(function(x) { return x.Id } );

db.collection.findAndModify({
    "query": {
        "_id": player,
        "OutstandingRewards.Id": { "$in": ids }
    },
    "update": {
        "$pull": {
            "OutstandingRewards": {
                "Id": { "$in": ids }
            }
        },
        "$addToSet": {
            "GameObjects": { "$each": input }
        }
    },
    "new": true
})
```

---

Just as a final note, even though you can to some extent, it is generally not a great idea to grow arrays out indefinitely or to particularly large numbers. Certainly never breaking 16MB for the document, and really should be kept below 500 before performance id notably affected. The actual handling of potentially large "lists" such as this is really another question in itself though.

But this at least gives you an approach for both removing and and inserting multiple items from one array and transferring to another array within the same document in a single atomic operation.

Comment: Ahhh... Yes I realise the "Paranoid Query" works if the MongoIds on the `OutstandingRewards` are kept persistent when they are converted to `GameObjects`!

Previously I was using `new MongoId()` when a GameObject was created, which would have made the `$nin` portion of the "Paranoid Query" always return true.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Logically speaking, we actually only need the `$nin` on `GameObjects` correct? The `$in` on `OutstandingRewards[]` returns true as long as at least 1 element matches right?  E.g. `Id{$in:[X, Y, Z]}` will return true if **any** of `Id:X`, `Id:Y`, `Id:Z` exists, where as `$nin` will return false if any of these exist right?

Comment: Ok, I've just messed around with the queries a little, to make the "Paranoid Query", absolutely strict (as per your intention), the correct operator to use would be `$all` instead of `$in`, correct? E.g. `"OutstandingRewards.Id'" => array( '$all' => $ids ), ...`